# Flutter Mockito to call original method

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

In Java variation of Mockito exists:

```
when( userProfileEntity.getFullName() ).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Is there anything similar for Flutter/Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created by myself - https://pub.dev/packages/dart_class_wrapper

```dart
// sample_test.dart
import 'sample.dart';

@GenerateWithMethodSetters([Sample])
import 'main.wrapper.dart';

void main() {
  test('Wrap connection', () {
    final obj = WrapperSample();
    obj.mockIsConnected = () => true;
    expect(obj.get(), 10);
    obj.mockIsConnected = () => false;
    expect(obj.get(), null);
  });
}
 
// sample.dart
class Sample {
  Sample();

  bool isConnected() {
    throw Exception('Emulate connection');
  }

  double? get() {
    if (isConnected()) {
      return 10;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the Flutter's Mockito package.
A workaround could be:

```dart
userProfileEntity=MockUserProfileEntity();
realUserProfileEntity=UserProfileEntity();

...
//when( userProfileEntity.getFullName() ).thenCallRealMethod();
when( userProfileEntity.getFullName() ).thenAnswer((_)=>realUserProfileEntity.getFullName(),);
```

Comment: That not giving an opportunity to mock methods that are used inside `getFullName`